# how to update BigQuery table using struct column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My Big Query table T1 is as below.

T1

```
A string,
B string,
C Record,
C.key string,
C.formula string,
D string
```

I want to update column D based on B and C, with query something like below.

```
update T1
set D = 'd1'
where B = 'b1' and C.formula = 'f1' ;
```

How to do that in BigQuery ?

Comment: What is the issue with your query?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: yes, it is giving error : Cannot access field formula on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<keySTRING, formula STRING>>

Comment: @SantanuGhosh So is column C in repeated mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even simpler version

```
update T1 t
set D = 'd1'
where B = 'b1' and
'f1' in (select formula from t.C);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a record for `C`.  You have an *array* of records.  So, you can use `unnest()`:

```
update T1
    set D = 'd1'
    where B = 'b1' and
          exists (select 1
                  from unnest(T1.C) as c_el
                  where c_el.formula = 'f1'
                 );
```